# Install elasticsearch as service using wix

Tags: elasticsearch, wix, windows-installer

I want to create an installer for a customized elasticsearch using WIX. When I use `<CustomAction>` to run `elasticsearch-service.bat` I get 1721 error. (I know that it is an antipattern to run bat files in your installer. But it seems the easiest way to install an elasticsearch service.)

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallService" Directory="elasticsearch" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand='"[elasticsearch]bin\elasticsearch-service.bat" install' Return="check" />
```

Also when I use `<SerivceInstall>` to create a service from `elasticsearch-service-x64.exe`, the service does not installed correctly and I can not start it. What is the best solution for doing this task?

Comment: What are the commands in the bat file?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul It is a file written in Apache Commons Daemon which checks JAVA_HOME, checks additional parameters(install, remove, ...) and then run the command according to parameters(in my case installing service)

Comment: It seems that for some reason this .bat is failing. Without its content it will be hard to tell why.